# EF 6.1.3 exception - Unable to cast object of type 'System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext' to type 'System.Data.Entity.DbContext'

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

When I instantiate a `DbContext`, I sometimes, but rarely am getting this exception. (Like once a week.)

```
[InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext' to type 'System.Data.Entity.DbContext'.]
   System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DatabaseLogFormatter.get_Context() +86
   System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DatabaseLogFormatter.Opened(DbConnection connection, DbConnectionInterceptionContext interceptionContext) +88
   System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.InternalDispatcher`1.Dispatch(TTarget target, Action`2 operation, TInterceptionContext interceptionContext, Action`3 executing, Action`3 executed) +373
   System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbConnectionDispatcher.Open(DbConnection connection, DbInterceptionContext interceptionContext) +503
   System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.<>c__DisplayClass1.<Execute>b__0() +18
   System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.Execute(Func`1 operation) +234
   System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.EntityConnection.Open() +318

[EntityException: The underlying provider failed on Open.]
   System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.EntityConnection.Open() +738
   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.EnsureConnection(Boolean shouldMonitorTransactions) +167
   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.ExecuteInTransaction(Func`1 func, IDbExecutionStrategy executionStrategy, Boolean startLocalTransaction, Boolean releaseConnectionOnSuccess) +60
   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.<>c__DisplayClass59.<ExecuteStoreCommand>b__57() +118
   System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.Execute(Func`1 operation) +206
...
...
```

The `DbContext` that I'm instantiating inherits from a base `DbContext` that I wrote. In that *constructor* I do this:

```
            this.Database.Log = s => this.sqlLogger.Debug(s);
            this.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(Resources.SqlServerConnectionInit); // throws here
```

I'm using EF 6.1.3.
When I look at the Microsoft code, in *DatabaseLogFormatter.cs*, I just totally don't see how it's possible for this exception to happen. I just don't see how that variable could actually be a `System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext`.

This code is being run in a web app. And once this exception happens, it will continue to happen - always - **until I restart the web server**. Restarting the database server doesn't fix anything.

I have found absolutely nothing on the internet about this.

FYI: SQL Server is the database server.

Comment: if you monitor the number of open connections at the DB level (you can do this using "exec sp_who2" or other connection monitoring tools) do you see the number of connections slowly grow? usually, there are only so many open connections allowed, either by the db engine, or through connection pooling settings deep in the EF engine. if you are getting refused connections look for potential places that connections are not getting closed.

Comment: Is there an inner exception with more info?

Comment: What is `Resources.SqlServerConnectionInit` (as in, what happens in that script)? And could you respond to earlier comments?

Comment: Another question is: how many context instances do you create. The phrase "The DbContext that I'm instantiating" makes me suspect that you have one long-lived static instance. BTW, you're wasting your bounty by not responding and leaving the question unclear.

Comment: @Gert - Resources.SqlServerConnectionInit is just some basic SQL Server commands - like turning ANSI stuff on or off. The same commands that, I think, automatically happen when you use SSMS. I can't remember exactly. But something like that.

Comment: @Gert - No, I don't have any long-lived DbContexts.

Comment: @Randy - No more inner exceptions. That's the end of the stack trace.

Comment: @Jeremy - I'll check. But, remember, even when I restart SQL Server, I keep getting the same exception from the web app. It's only when I restart the web app that things clear up. But, even if that were so, why would I get a EF code exception like that? And if you look at Microsoft's EF 6.1.3 code, it looks like it's impossible for such an Exception to happen.

Comment: The only possible point of failure is that `DatabaseLogFormatter.Context` is a weak reference (to prevent a memory leak when the `Log` delegate is never GC'ed). That means that its `Target` must be cast back to `DbContext` when the context must be addressed. But I don't see any reason why EF would replace the reference by an `ObjectContext` instance. Do you have any interceptors attached?

Answer (score -1):

Please pay attention to exception :

*Unable to **cast** object of type [`System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.entity.dbcontext?view=entity-framework-6.2.0) to type [`System.Data.Entity.DbContext`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.entity.dbcontext?view=entity-framework-6.2.0)*

Both are classes inside *EntityFramework.dll*, available for +6.x version. You called both in your project which creates a baffling condition. Next exception is the result of first one, *The underlying provider failed on Open*. In this way, it can't access data.

#### `DbContext` vs `ObjectContext`

Shortly, `DbContext` is just a wrapper around `ObjectContext`. `ObjectContext` is the top-level object, while `DbContext` instance represents a combination of the Unit Of Work and Repository patterns, Although `DbContext` is conceptually similar to `ObjectContext`.

**Solution**: Check the (configuration including context) parts of your code where a mismatch exists in order to avoid casting.

Comment: The exception happens in the EF code, not mine.

Comment: @N73k Do you mean this is an EF internal BUG? :) This is all about your project configuration, not about EF!